# Blazor unable to reach login.microsoftonline.com due to network setup

Tags: blazor, openid-connect, kestrel-http-server, microsoft-entra-id

I have a Blazor .NET 8 server-side app working correctly on an unsecured machine, and am trying to move it to a machine that has no direct outbound internet access; only via web proxy.  The app uses OpenIdConnect and users should log in using Microsoft Entra ID.

When a user tries to log in, the server console logs the following errors (I have obscured my Tenant ID from the URL):

- Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '21/03/2024 3:22:28 am +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
- ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known. (login.microsoftonline.com:443)
- ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.

However, if I paste the exact same URL into MS Edge running on the same machine as is hosting the Blazor app, it retrieves the document successfully. The browser uses the proxy configuration from System > Proxy Settings, but Kestrel doesn't seem to use this.

The relevant code from Program.cs is:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

and in `appsettings.json` under `"AzureAD"`, it has `"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",` and then the other AzureAD parameters.

Is it possible to either:

- Tell Kestrel to use the system proxy settings to retrieve this configuration document, or
- Make some change to the app source so that it does not need to do this step at all? (E.g. can I save the document locally and read it)

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation for what can go in the "Kestrel" section of appsettings.json. (Currently only have Endpoints set)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596596/website-authenticating-users-against-aad-can-the-openid-document-be-provided-of Similar question , but the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: I don't believe Kestrel is involved at all - the problem is a `HttpWebRequest` being made from within your Azure Entra client is not correctly autodetecting and using the proxy settings. I don't know how/where you're running this, but I imagine if it's run as a Windows service but proxy config is a per-user setting then that would explain it. There are a bunch of different ways to prompt .NET's `HttpClient` and `HttpWebRequest` to use proxy autodiscovery and manual config - but you'll need to do more digging to find out.

Comment: @Dai agree Kestrel is not involved. I have found that by doing `SetEnvironmentVariable` with `ALL_PROXY`, then it will use that address as proxy.  But then it also tries to use the proxy for my database connection, which I don't want . Can you elaborate on how to configure proxy for a HttpClient (if we presume that's how the Entra client code works)